# MySQL event scheduler query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When I write following code on SQL tab of `phpmyadmin`:

```
    DELIMITER $$    
    CREATE 
        EVENT `near_end_warranty` 
        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
        DO BEGIN

        DECLARE numrow int;
        SELECT COUNT(id) FROM equipments INTO numrow WHERE  
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)<5 AND                
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)>0;

        IF numrow>0 THEN
        INSERT INTO notifications 
            (eq_id,start_date,end_date,name,type,message,created_by,modified_by,
            created_on,modified_on)
        SELECT eq_id,warranty_start_date,warranty_end_date,'warranty','ending soon',
               'warranty ends soon for','System','System',NOW(),NOW()
        FROM equipments WHERE 
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)<5 AND  
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)>0;
        END IF;         
    END $$    
DELIMITER ;
```

It shows following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)<5 AND
>   TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW()' at line 7

I checked and tried to find error but couldn't. Please someone help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INTO` clause has to go *after* the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM equipments 
WHERE  
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)<5 AND                
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)>0
INTO numrow;
```

See the syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) (this is the manual that the error message told you to check).

All the clauses have to be in the order specified, there's no flexibility.

Actually, there's an exception for the `INTO` clause, it can also go right after the `SELECT` list. But it can't go after `FROM`. So you could also write:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO numrows
FROM equipments 
WHERE  
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)<5 AND                
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK,NOW(),warranty_end_date)>0;
```